# How do we prove that the complement of Universal set is the null set and vice versa?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Is there a rigid proof of the lemma? I've seen abstract statements and I do understand that it is true. It is very intuitive. However, I do not understand if there's a *mathematical way* (like in proper steps, not just an explanation).

Is there one? If so, how would you approach it?

Comment: I think calling this a lemma is a bit of an overstatement. It's just an immediate consequence of the definition. There is nothing in the empty set, so everything that is not in the empty set is just everything. Everthing is in the universal set, so there is no one thing not in the universal set, so the complement is empty.

Comment: The idea of a universal set is potentially problematic (see eg the Russell Paradox). How are you defining a complement?

Comment: @tomasz I feel the same.

Comment: Quite... We can talk about a complement *with respect to a specific "universal set"* such as the complement of $\{1,2\}$ with respect to the universal set $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ being $\{3,4,5\}$... but when we do not specify what the universal set was then there is no way to adequately define the complement of $\{1,2\}$ is in general.  There is no *universal* universal set.

Comment: @MarkBennet I define the complement of a set X as a set which contains the whole universal set except the elements present in X.

Comment: We're trying to get you to use the proper grammar for that phrase... The complement of a set $X$ **with respect to a specified universal set $\Omega$** is a set which contains the whole universal set except the elements present in $X$.  That bolded section in the middle can not be skipped.

Comment: @JMoravitz so the definition of universal set always varies accordingly. Therefore, there cannot be any solid proofs I believe. Just an abstract arguement.

Comment: No, for any "universal" set, it's an immediate consequence of the definition, as @tomasz said.  There's nothing shaky, or non-mathematical about it.

Comment: @Justanotherperson: Nonsense. An abstract argument can be a solid proof (for any reasonable definition of "solid proof").

Comment: "I define the complement of a set X as a set which contains the whole universal set except the elements present in X."  Well, then *by definition* the complement of the universal set as a set that contains the whole universal set except the the elements present in the universal set.  Other than the elements in the universal set there are not elements in the universal set so the the complement of the universal set is a set with no elements, i.e. the empty set. And likewise....

Comment: .... the complement of the empty set contains the whole universal sect except for the elements present in $\emptyset$.  But no elements are present in the empty set so the complement of the empty set is the whole universal set with no exceptions.

Comment: "so the definition of universal set always varies accordingly."  No. The universal set is *always* and unambiguously defined with respect to a set.  There is nothing "varying" about that.  You might as well say the definition of an even number varies depending upon whether it is $2\times 3$ or $2 \times 7$ or some other number. "Therefore, there cannot be any solid proofs"  Why on earth would that mean there can't be a solid proof?  And there is *nothing* abstract about tomasz argument.  His (her?) argument is very solid based on a solid definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"like in proper steps, not just an explanation" The steps of a proof by definition is a statement of the definition and a demonstration that all the criteria apply.

Definition:  $X^c = \{x \in U| x\not \in X\}$.

So $U^c = \{x\in U| x\not \in U\}=\{x|x \in U$ and $x\not \in U\}$.  As $x \in U$ and $x\not \in U$ are contradictory statements this can never occur and so $U^c$ can have no elements and $U^c = \emptyset$.

And $\emptyset^c = \{x \in U| x\not \in X\}$.  As no $x \in \emptyset$ then $x \in U \implies x \not \in \emptyset$ so $\emptyset^c=\{x\in U| x\not \in X\} = \{x \in U\} = U$.

That *is* the mathematical way.

Answer (score 0):

There's two steps in the "proof" of the statement (the quotes here are because one could argue if this can be considered as a proof or not); defining well your objects and then letting the definitions spit out the result. In this case we need three basic notions: universal set, complement of a set with respect to another set and empty set.

The universal set is just some set $\Omega$ that we fix, meaning that all elements and subsets which we will consider from now onwards will belong and be contained in $\Omega$, respectively. The complement of a subset $X \subseteq\Omega$ is defined as $$X^c= \{ x \in \Omega : x \notin X\}.\tag{$\dagger$}$$ Note that I have specified that $X$ is a subset of our universal set $\Omega$, so the notation in $(\dagger)$ seems slightly misleading since it hides this fact; note however that we've established before that all subsets are taken with respect to $\Omega$, so this is not a real issue. This is way we call $\Omega$ *universal*, so that when we argue about such set theoretic operations we can shorten our arguments by not repeating each time that the complement of $X$ is taken with respect to $\Omega$, as in our example.

Now, recalling that $\varnothing$ is the (unique) set which has no elements in it, the argument would go as follows:

> $$\begin{align} \Omega^c &= \{ x \in \Omega : x \notin \Omega \} &\text{ by definition of complement}\\ &= \varnothing &\text{by definition of }\varnothing\end{align}$$

If you want to be really picky, you could justify even further the last equality as follows.

> Trivially $\varnothing \subseteq \{ x \in \Omega : x \notin \Omega \}$, so it is left for us to prove the other inclusion. Assume for contradiction it is false, i.e. there is $a \in \{ x \in \Omega : x \notin \Omega \}$ such that $a \notin \varnothing$. Then, since $\{ x \in \Omega : x \notin \Omega \} \subseteq \Omega$, we have that $a \in \Omega$; but since $a \in \{ x \in \Omega : x \notin \Omega \}$ we also have that $a \notin \Omega$, so our assumption is false and equality follows.

Showing that $\varnothing^c = \Omega$ is analogous. As you see, the problem here is not in the argument itself, but in how you are defining the objects you are working with.